# Docker running JHipster refused connecting to Postgree SQL DB?

Tags: docker, jhipster

maybe I misunderstood something.

I just build a monolith JHipser with Postgree SQL database as product database. I builed a Docker image of the application "./mvnw package -Pprod verify jib:build". Locally, it runs fine with Postgree SQL DB running etc. but when uploading and running the image to my Docker on my NAS it cannot connect to Postgree SQL.

I just have ONE container in the Docker that is started from the Docker image i uploaded. Shouldn't the image have the PostgreeSQL database included and run or should I install a PostgreeSQL seperatly and how ?

The error when starting the image running only one container is "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is "

Comment: A Docker image almost never contains a relational database; you'll have to start it separately, and when you do, it won't be accessible via `localhost` ("this container").  Several of the official [Docker sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) have an application and a database paired together.

Answer (score 3):

The created image contains just your application. You have to run a dedicated PSQL on your nas (e.g. via Docker) and configure the application to connect to that database (e.g. via environment variables on the application image).